# Unable to view commits on Sentry Releases page after configuration

Tags: node.js, github, sentry

We have integrated sentry project with our GitHub repositories, but we are unable to view commits information in Sentry releases page.

We have performed the following steps:

- Configured SDK in all our repositories. So we have handled and
  unhandled exceptions coming from these on our sentry.
- Then integrated github repositories with sentry.
- Thirdly we also created a release for one of our repositories by installing sentry CLI and associated commits by using this command: `sentry-cli releases set-commits --auto $VERSION`

After performing the above steps, we are still unable to gets commits information from the repository the integration has been setup. Please help what are we missing to understand or is there any addition step that we have to perform.

For reference, here is the sdk configuration:

```
Sentry.init({
    dsn: 'https://xyz@xyz.ingest.sentry.io/292307',
    release: '@1.0.0',
    debug: true,
    environment: config.env,
    serverName: 'Webhook',
    sendDefaultPii: true
  })
```

When we run create new release command we get the following response:

> Created release 1.0.0

When we associate commits to the release we get the following response:

[image]

On sentry releases, page we can see the release but commits info is not being shown.

[image]

Can anyone help me understand what we are doing wrong or is there an additional step that we need to perform to get the commits info?